# Enabling Camera LED alone without Camera.open in Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to enable only LED of the device without using `Camera.open()` in Android?

Since LED light is also a separate hardware in mobile, there should be way to access it alone without using `Camera.open()` and setting Torch parameter to it.

The reason why I am asking is I have a Video App which is built in AIR which requires Flash to enabled with Camera also. The Camera will be made open by AIR and Flash will be enabled using Android Native extension. But its not working as we cannot have multiple camera instance opened at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to open the `Camera` with `Camera.open()` and then `setFlashMode()` to `FLASH_MODE_TORCH` to enable the LED light continuously. The LED is supposed to go off when the `Camera` is closed. And you need to close the `Camera` when your process goes into the background. So you really can't do this in a second app.

How about using ANE to call `setFlashMode()`? That would really be the right way to do it. I have never tried it directly so do not know if there's a catch that stops it from working.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I have already created an ANE which will enable FLash along with Camera. THe problem is my existing AIR app is a video chat app which is already using Camera, so I had a button called Flash, on click of it will enable ANE's flash which will also use Camera.open() . Finally my device will try to access camera twice, secondly accessed camera which is flash will not be open as because already my AIR uses camera.... so is I raised a question of accessing LED hardware without camera....

Comment: Yes my suggestion is to see if there is a way to get the already open Camera. Yes you can't open twice.